# How do I make a request using HTTP basic authentication with native C++?

Tags: c++, http, authentication, basic-authentication, wininet

I'm trying to use `HttpSendRequest` in native `C++` to send a basic authentication request to a server.  Does anyone have any examples on how to accomplish this?

**Edit:** So far I've tried encoding the username and password as a base 64 string, example, `string auth = "myuser:mypassword"` then encoded that into base 64 so it returns a string like `dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==`.

Then I create a new string that prepends basic to the encoded string, `string encoded = "Basic " + "dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA=="`

Then I connect to the server using `InternetOpen` and `HttpOpenRequest` as a `POST` and those pass successfully.

Then I try passing the encoded string I made to the server using `HttpSendRequest`

```
if (HttpSendRequest(hRequest, encoded, sizeof(encoded), NULL, 0)) {
  return 1;
 } else {
  return GetLastError();
}
```

Not sure what exactly is wrong, but it always returns

> error code 12150, ERROR_HTTP_HEADER_NOT_FOUND.

Comment: Please let us know what you've tried. Currently, you're asking for an example, which would be an off-site resource. This goes against the posting guidelines: _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."_

Comment: added problem description and current attempt to main post

Comment: Thanks for adding those details, they help your post. Also, I formatted your code using a code block, but that won't show up until the edit passes through a review. Also, up-voted your code after the edits (and I wasn't the down-vote before).